# python: why "IndentationError: expected an indented block" for this code?

Tags: python

Refer to [Listing 9. Iteration and a dictionary](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-python7/)

```
>>> d = {0: 'zero', 3: 'a tuple', 'two': [0, 1, 2], 'one': 1}
>>> for k in d.iterkeys():
... print(d[k])
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(d[k])
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Why?

Comment: Yeah, don't trust the code on that page, as cwallenpoole points out it's riddled with errors.

Comment: Just felt confused the way that some people voted down my question. What is the point? If you vote down, as least give a reason.

Comment: Some guesses at why the downvotes (none from me) 1. You didn't explain what you tried to fix the problem. This is the big one -- _show effort_ is the core rule of asking questions on SO. 2. There is very little descriptive text in general. 3. The title has _nothing_ to do with the error you had. 4. The error seems self-descriptive. 5. The problem is very basic.

Comment: Over 2/3rds of your _300_ questions have a score of 1 or lower -- this is a sign that you need to do more to follow the reccomendations on the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 doesn't have `iterkeys`. Just use:

```
for k in d:
    print(d[k])
```

or even better:

```
for v in d.values():
    print(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even when using the Python interactive interpreter, you need to make sure you have *some* indentation for a new block of code.

This:

```
>>> for k in d.iterkeys():
... print(d[k])
```

Should be this:

```
>>> for k in d.iterkeys():
...     print(d[k])
```

---

As an aside: that link has a number of errors in what should be the expected output, possibly some copy/paste problem?